# antrl4 why can not parse Compaire lexer but can parse compaire parser

Tags: antlr4

```
grammar test;

parse:(expr|type)EOF ;

type: ID('<'ID'>')?;
expr:ID Compaire ID;

Compaire:'>' | '<';

ID:[a-z];
```

I am learning antlr4 , why can not parse `Compaire lexer` but can parse `compaire parser`

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you use a string literal in a parser rule, you are declaring a token for that string literal. (Look at the generated .tokens file.) Therefore, when the lexer sees `<`, it finds that implicitly declared string literal, not a `Compaire` because Antlr lexers matches (1) the longest string first, (2) if two or more rules match an equal-lengthed string, the first one wins. Unfold `Compaire` into the `expr` and get rid of `Compaire`. Or, rename `Compaire` to `compaire`. If you want to make the tokens explicit, add lexer rules `LT: '<'; GT: '>';` to your grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: when using tokens like `'<'` or `'>'` in parser rules, what really happens is this:

```
type : ID ('<' ID '>')?;
expr : ID Compaire ID;

T__1     : '<';
T__2     : '>';
Compaire : '>' | '<';

ID:[a-z];
```

In other words, for all of the `'...'` tokens ANTLR encounters inside parser rules (that cannot be directly mapped to lexer rules!), ANTLR will create a lexer rule behind the scenes. And in your case, this causes that the token `Compaire` will never be created because `T__1` and `T__2` already match these chars.

To fix it, you could do:

```
// the parser now uses LT and GT, and will not create T__1 and T__2
type : ID ('<' ID '>')?; 
expr : ID compaire ID;

compaire : GT | LT;

GT : '>';
LT : '<';
```

The above will work, but I recommend to not use literal tokens inside your parser rules and always do:

```
type : ID (LT ID GT)?; 
expr : ID compaire ID;

compaire : GT | LT;

GT : '>';
LT : '<';
```

Comment: It is mean the priority is `grammar` > `'...'`tokens > `lexical`?

Comment: Yes, the literal tokens defined in parser rules (`’…’`) have a higher priority.